# image editor to add to my web site

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, image-manipulation

hEY,

Do You know any image editor with functions like draw on picture which I can add to my html web site ? It's something like paint for www

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Pixlr editor](http://pixlr.com/) and their [developer API](http://pixlr.com/developer/api/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather broad, but here is an Ajax Whiteboard that might get you started:

[Ajax Whiteboard](http://cristian.nexcess.net/ajax/whiteboard/)